# c# xml array into oracle stored procedure

Tags: c#, oracle

I have and `xml` message that contains an array of string data, smth like this :

```
<DataList>
  <Data>some data no 1</Data>
  <Data>some data no 2</Data>
</DataList>
```

I store it in my 2 classes:

```
[XmlElement("DataList")]
public DataList DataList { get; set; }
```

and for the array:

```
public struct DataList
 {
   [XmlElement]
   public string Data { get; set; }
 }
```

So , i need to pass this array as an `input parmater` to my `oracle stored procedure`

How am I suppose to do that, both on oracle and c# sides? (by creating a table\refcursor in oracle and passing them as a ref cursor? or by using `for` 
 loop?)

```
parameter.Add("Data", OracleDbType.-don't know-).Value = DataList.Data; or just DataList?
```

Comment: See the linked answer - just use `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE stringarray AS TABLE OF CLOB;` (or you can try `TABLE OF XMLTYPE` OR `TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000)` if the xml will be small enough) and then wrap it in `XMLTYPE()` at the other end.

Comment: Oops... a better duplicate would have been [Calling Stored procedures from C# with Oracle type like Table of CustomType](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21305028/1509264) or [Calling oracle package function with table of varchar2(100) index by binary_integer datatype as a parameter from c# .net](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21305028/1509264)

Comment: 1st variant: c# parameter.Add("Data", OracleDbType.XmlType).Value = DataList; , in oracle: type data_array IS TABLE OF XMLTYPE; -  i'm getting the c# error: Unsupported column datatype.

Comment: 2nd try: c#parameter.Add("Data", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = DataList; oracle - type data_array IS TABLE OF Varchar2; getting the oracle error - wrong number or types of arguments in call

Comment: Pass it as a `TABLE OF CLOB` or `TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000)` (depending on the maximum size of your XML data) - you may also need to use `INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21306124/1509264.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/29605713/1509264. You need to make sure you set `parameter.CollectionType` to the appropriate type (i.e. `OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray` if you are using `TABLE OF X INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER`).

Comment: i've already tried to pass it a table of varchar2, added index by, didn't make any difference. I understood the part of oracle. The question is how to pass the parameters via c#. OracleDbType.Varchar2 or XMLType both not working in here.

Comment: I've reopened the question so you can, hopefully, get some more help (although I still believe the question should be answered by one of the questions I have already linked). Please edit your question and post a [MCVE] of your attempt and the full error messages.